# When stored data in localstorage first time it will be stored but second time I try to store then it display error push is not function why?

Tags: javascript, html

**Html code**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <button onclick="empShow()">Click</button>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function empShow(){
    let emp=[];
    let name=document.getElementById('userName').value;
    let data={UserName:name};
     emp=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('empData')) || [];
    emp.push(data); //when i try to push data second time it display emp.push is not function.
    localStorage.setItem('empData',JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

[When I change localstroge key then it is stored but when run the second time it will display error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWFA5.png)

Comment: It should be `JSON.stringify(emp)`, not `JSON.stringify(data)`

Answer (score 0):

While inserting the data for the fist time in localStorage:

```
localStorage.getItem('empData')
```

was `null`. Now at that (first) time,

```
null || []
```

resulted into `[]`. i.e. an array.

Then in the next line you called push method on an array. It worked. The 2nd time however,

```
localStorage.getItem('empData')
```

was not null. Let's consider the first time you entered "Test" in the text box. So the value of `localStorage.getItem('empData')` becomes '{"UserName":"test"}'.

The string value parsed into a JSON object transformed variable emp a JSON variable.
A JSON value ORed with the empty array [] resulted into the JSON itself this time, which is not an array and does not have a push method either. As a result you are getting that error.

Comment: @Anjali So far I only know what the code does. The final purpose is yet not clear. May be I could answer more constructively if the required output is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

While storing the data always setItem
By using JSON.stringify();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).